# How to show data from file without store data in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in RoR.

I want to upload xml file, parse it, analyze and show results on same or next page.
I read a lot of tutorials, but they describe how to upload file, parse, store data in DB.
For example: [Upload and Parse a XML File with Ruby on Rails, Paperclip and Nokogiri](http://larsgebhardt.de/parse-xml-with-ruby-on-rails-paperclip-and-nokogiri/)

Could you, please, describe how to do that without store data in DB?

I think its something like this:

1. Make controller with two pages, make classes for data.
2. Call controller method from first page (with helper or without)
3. Upload and parse file and fill object with data from file
4. Show data from object on next page.

But I don't know is it right or not.
I will be very appreciate for manuals/tutorials/etc which can help me.

Comment: yes, what you've suggested sounds right. How about you have a go at coding all the bits that you can figure out how to do. See how it goes. It looks like you should be able to do it fairly well by yourself. If you encounter a problem with one part, come back and ask us to help you fix that bit.